# Fotorama 'skipping' a slide when clicking arrows in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, fotorama

I'm not very familiar with jquery so I'm a tad stuck!

I've googled and I can't see anyone else with the same problem.

It seems that the fotorama carousel is skipping my middle slide when I click the arrows.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nVu8f/

```
<div class="fotorama" data-width="300" data-height="300">
<div class="project-holder">
    <a href="#" class="front-news-title">Title number 1</a>
    <br /><br />
    <img src="http://churchm.ag/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/coding.png" />
    <p>A bit of a description here</p>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
</div>
<div class="project-holder">
    <a href="#" class="front-news-title">Title number 2</a>
    <br /><br />
    <img src="http://jarrpa.net/uploads//2011/12/coding-150x150.jpg" />
    <p>A bit more of a description here</p>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
</div>
<div class="project-holder">
    <a href="#" class="front-news-title">Title number 3</a>
    <br /><br />
    <img src="https://info.examtime.com/files/2013/04/html-150x150.jpg" />
    <p>Some description here</p>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

**NOTE** Just found out it's only in chrome that this happens

Comment: works fine for me too (BTW does not work at all on IE)

Comment: Oh wow... It's only chrome it isn't working in :/

Comment: @phron jsfiddle example doesn't work on IE but my live version works :s